# LibGdx Tiled Map with proper dimensions given screen size

Tags: android, libgdx, tiled

I have set up my Tiled Map likes so:

```
 level = new Level("level_1.tmx");
    renderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(level.getMap(), UNIT_SCALE);
    spriteBatch = renderer.getBatch();
    debugRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();

    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.setToOrtho(false, 18, 10); //View is 18 by 10 tiles 
    camera.update();
```

However, since the number of tiles is hardcoded in, the screen will accordingly stretch with different screen sizes.

How do I customize the screen width so that it has the proper ratio and will properly scale to fill the screen with LibGDX and Android?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see more tiled area on a screen, when its resolution more than origin, when you must set new camera viewport:
`camera.setToOrtho(false, Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / YOUR_TILE_PIXEL_WIDTH, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / YOUR_TILE_PIXEL_HEIGHT)`
But if you always want to see the same amount of tiles on the screen, streched if screen resolution more than origin, then use [StretchViewport](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/viewport/StretchViewport.html)

[and take a look here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports)